# web api stopped working after adding odata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, odata, asp.net-web-api

WebApi's were working fine, then I added a few odata controllers, now my webapi's return not found.  I assume its in the routing somewhere but I don't see it.  returns 404 not found.  how do I fix my webapi's to return data gain.

Global Config

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();           
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Web API Config

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<pp_tsr_accounts_tab_Result>("pp_tsr_accounts_tab_Result");
            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
```

Call

```
http://localhost:xxx/api/pp_tsr_offer_calc_Result/Getpp_tsr_offer_calc_Result?id=0801314923
```

Answer (score 0):

well I win the idiot award.

```
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

not

```
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
```